# Cant run an IIFE inside a template

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

I'm using a `<template>` element but the javascript code inside it wont run. i'm using an IIFE to get it running immediately but no luck.

```html
<div id="content">
  initial text
</div>

<template>
  <script>
    (function(){
        document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = 'new text';
    })();
  </script>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you *use* the template anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates content doesn't render to the DOM, hence script wont run.

from the [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) (first paragraph):

> The HTML  element is a mechanism for holding client-side
>   content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may
>   subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript.

**EDIT**
Following your comment on how to run the code, there are couple of ways. the simple one is grabbing it's content and drop it in the `DOM`:

```html
<div id="content">
  initial text
</div>


<template>
  <script>
    (function(){
        document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = 'new text';
    })();
  </script>
</template>

<script>
   var content = document.querySelector('template').content;
   document.body.appendChild(content,true);
</script>
```

Comment: @JJJ that's true if it is your template. what if this template is coming from a third party?